# JSLint won't recognize getElementById

Tags: javascript, function, getelementbyid, jslint

JSLint gives errors with simple function, running on brackets with JSLint.

Javascript:

```
function soundSorry() {
    getElementById("player").play();
}
```

Error codes:

```
2   Missing 'use strict' statement. getElementById("player").play();
2   'getElementById' was used before it was defined. getElementById("player").play();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `document` prefix. As [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is defined on `document` object you've to call it using `document` object as follow:

```
document.getElementById("player").play();
// ^^^^^^
```

[**Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)